# Storybook nuxt build does not includes decorators

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, storybook

**TLDR:
Problem with nuxt + storybook + vuetify build**

I've created a new project using Nuxt.js, Vuetify, and Storybook.

The Storybook dev server is working great, I only had to add a single decorator to the nuxt config:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
storybook: {
    decorators: [
      // VApp decorator for Vuetify
      '<v-app><div><story/></div></v-app>',
    ],
  },
```

The only problem that is seems that when running the build it does not load the decorators so the Storybook does not represent the visual aspect properly.

```js
// package.json
"storybook": "nuxt storybook",
"storybook:build": "nuxt storybook build"
```

Note:
I did use the official [nuxt storybook](https://storybook.nuxtjs.org/)

Example of Dev:

[image]

Example of Build:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it took me a few trials and errors but I've made it work.

### 1) Add Vuetify as a plugin

The first thing that we would like to do is create a `vuetify.js` file in the plugin directory

```
.
├── plugins
│   └── vuetify.js
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors';
import { themes } from '~/config/themes';

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default (ctx) => {
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true,
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          ...themes.light,
        },
      },
    },
  });
  ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify;
  ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework;
};
```

### 2) Update nuxt config to load Vuetify

In your `nuxt.config.js` make sure you remove the Vuetify config and add vuetify as a plugin like so:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
  plugins: ['@/plugins/vuetify.js'],
```

### 3) Add Storybook Decorator

Add a Vuetify decorator to support Vuetify in all of the Storybook stories.
In your `nuxt.config.js` add the following decorator

```js
// nuxt.config.js

  storybook: {
    // Options
    decorators: [
      // VApp decorator for Vuetify
      `<v-app id='vuetify-storybook-decorator'><div><story/></div></v-app>`,
    ],
  },
```

### 4) Fix Storybook Visibility

To prevent eatch story taking too full screen height and allowing presenting more then a single story in a view, we would override the default vuetify min-height only in storybook;

In your `nuxt.config.js` file load a `storybook.scss` like so

```js
// nuxt.config.js

 // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
 css: ['@/assets/storybook.scss'],
```

And in your assets folder add the `storybook.scss` file:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── storybook.scss
```

```css
/* storybook.scss */

#vuetify-storybook-decorator {
  // Remove the storybook full height of all components
  .v-application--wrap {
    min-height: unset;
  }
}
```

### 5) Build the project

Add the build comand to your `package.json`

```json
// package.json
{
    "storybook": "nuxt storybook",
    "storybook:build": "nuxt storybook build"
}
```

Then run in the command line `yarn storybook:build`

The build will be placed in `/storybook-static`;
You can view the build by running any server on that folder, for example:

```sh
$ npx http-server ./storybook-static
```

**That's it, I hope it would be helpfull:)**